# Java entering test score validation

Tags: java, validation, testing

I am trying to output the amount of test scores between 5 and 35.  I do get an invalid entry when the integer entered is below 5 or above 35, which is required.  However, when I enter a number between 5 and 35, nothing happens.  I get a blank line.  The only way I can get "Enter Score" to show up is when I enter another number and press "Enter/Return". What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

============================

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ValidatedTestScoreApp 
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";
    while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
    {

        int scoreTotal = 0;
        int scoreCount = 0;
        int testScore = 0;
        int maximumScore = 0;
        int minimumScore = 100;

        // get the number of scores to be entered
        int amtTest = getIntWithinRange(sc,"Enter the number of test scores to be entered: ", 5, 35);
        int numberOfEntries = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        sc.nextLine(); 

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfEntries; i++)
        {

            int testScores = getIntWithinRange(sc, "Enter score " + i + ": ", 1, 100);
            testScore = sc.nextInt();

            // accumulate score count and score total
            if (testScore <= 100)
            {
                scoreCount += 1;
                scoreTotal += testScore;
                maximumScore = Math.max(maximumScore, testScore);
                minimumScore = Math.min(minimumScore, testScore);
            }
            else if (testScore != 999)

            {
                System.out.println("Invalid entry, not counted");
                i--;
            }
        }

        // calculate the average score
        double averageScore = (double) scoreTotal / (double) scoreCount;

        // display the results
        NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        number.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);

        String message = "\n" +
                         "Score count:   " + scoreCount + "\n"
                       + "Score total:   " + scoreTotal + "\n"
                       + "Average score: " + number.format(averageScore) + "\n"
                       + "Minimum score: " + minimumScore + "\n"
                       + "Maximum score: " + maximumScore + "\n";
        System.out.println(message);

        // see if the user wants to enter more test scores
        System.out.print("Enter more test scores? (y/n): ");
        choice = sc.next();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
public static int getInt(Scanner sc, String prompt)
{
    int i = 0;
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (isValid == false)
    {

        System.out.print(prompt);
        if (sc.hasNextInt())
        {
            i = sc.nextInt();
            isValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error! Invalid integer value. Try again.");
        }
        sc.nextLine(); 
    }
    return i;
}


public static int getIntWithinRange(Scanner sc, String prompt,
int min, int max)
{
    int i = 0;
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (isValid == false)
    {
        i = getInt(sc, prompt);
        if (i <= min)
            System.out.println(
                "Error! Number must be greater than " + min + ".");
        else if (i >= max)
            System.out.println(
                "Error! Number must be less than " + max + ".");
    else
            isValid = true;
    }
    return i;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to read the values multiple times.

```
 int testScores = getIntWithinRange(sc, "Enter score " + i + ": ", 1, 100);
 testScore = sc.nextInt();
```

Here you already got the value from the `getIntWithinRangeMethod`, but on the next line you are reading it again.

Also what are the `amtTest` and `testScores` variables good for? I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I guess you need to do these two changes:

```
            // get the number of scores to be entered
//            int amtTest = getIntWithinRange(sc, "Enter the number of test scores to be entered: ", 5, 35);
//            int numberOfEntries = sc.nextInt();
        int numberOfEntries = getInt(sc, "Enter the number of test scores to be entered: ");
//            System.out.println();
//            sc.nextLine();

...

//          int testScores = getIntWithinRange(sc, "Enter score " + i + ": ", 1, 100);
            testScore = getIntWithinRange(sc, "Enter score " + i + ": ", 1, 100);
```

After this, the programs behaves fine and I get this:

```
Enter the number of test scores to be entered: 2
Enter score 1: 5
Enter score 2: 6

Score count:   2
Score total:   11
Average score: 5.5
Minimum score: 5
Maximum score: 6

Enter more test scores? (y/n):
```

Comment: so do i move or delete getIntWithinRangeMethod elsewhere?

Comment: See my update. After the changes I've done to your code it behaves as I would expect it should.

Comment: Your code works, but I need to specify the amount of test scores range from 5 to 35.  For example, when I enter 36 test scores, I am still getting  the output to enter an enter score when I should be getting a message that that number is too big. (or enter 4 test scores meaning that the number is too small.)

Comment: Then use ```getIntWithinRange```. I didn't fully understand it. I thought that only the actual score should be limited, not number of entries.

Comment: I think i know what to do now.  Thank you for your help.